# null value for list when ItemsSource is binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, combobox

My project is written in c# using Entity Framework. I set for a combobox a binding ItemsSource from a table.

In the initial state - a null value is shown in the box (no exists null item in the table). After I choose one of the items, i can't to select null again. Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us what have you done so far ?, so we can find where the issue is !

Comment: 1. my_combobox.ItemsSource = db_connection.table;
my_combobox.Items.Add(null);  : is not valid while ItemsSource is in use....  2. Items.Add(null);
my_combobox.ItemsSource = db_connection.table;

error: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

3. 
EntityType e = new EntityType();
e = null;
db_connection.table.add(e);
my_combobox.ItemsSource = db_connection.table;

this option solves the problem, but it added a row to table when excuted db_connection.SaveChanges();

Comment: 4.
I know that i can to use with ToList() but i want to save the connection between items and database for other actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you get to a List of object all the values from database and then add a null value to list after that bind the values using DataSource? ex:

```
List<string> values=new List<string>();
values.Add("");
values.AddRange({here you call a method which returns as List<string>(or anything) with the values from db});
my_combobox.DataSource=values;
```

Comment: because i want to save the connection between items and database for other actions.

Comment: You can keep the connection open and manipulate the data as you wish, but this is the way i used a lot of times and it's fast :)

Comment: try it but don't close the connection!

Comment: Thanks. Your idea to use with AddRenge helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can you bind your Combobox to a composite collection where first item is a Blank comboBoxItem and other is bound to your list from ef.